# Looping transition in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Essential exposition: I'm a bit of a D3 newbie.

My goal is to have a line move from point A to point B, then immediately reappear at point A and repeat that transition.  I've tried a lot of different things, but this is the closest I've come.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);

// code, code, code, irrelevant code...

function timeForTimeline(){ // har
    var timeline = svg.append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr({
            'x1': 0,
            'y1': 130,
            'x2': 168,
            'y2': 130
        });
    (function repeat() {
        timeline = timeline
            .transition()
            .duration(4000)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr({
                'x1': 0,
                'y1': 430,
                'x2': 168,
                'y2': 430   
            })
            .each("end", function(){
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .attr({
                        'x1': 0,
                        'y1': 130,
                        'x2': 168,
                        'y2': 130
                    })
                    .each("end", repeat);
            });
    })();
};
```

The result is an excellent starting transition, followed by the line quickly jumping between point A and point B WITHOUT the `duration(4000)` bit taking effect.  I've also tried removing the line at the bottom (`d3.select(this).remove()`) then appending a new one at the top of each call to repeat().  I've also tried just resetting x1, x2, y1, and y2 and skipping the transition altogether.  I'm not saying I attempted those correctly, but my results were either no lines at all, infinite lines, or a single line that reaches point B and stays there.

Any other suggestions on how to accomplish my (likely very simplistic) goal?  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't need to specify the starting coordinates twice. You could just assign the initial coordinates inside the repeat function and call it immediately like so:

```
function timeForTimeline() {
    var timeline = svg.append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue");

    repeat();

    function repeat() {
      timeline.attr({
        'x1': 0,
        'y1': 130,
        'x2': 168,
        'y2': 130
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(4000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr({
        'x1': 0,
        'y1': 430,
        'x2': 168,
        'y2': 430   
      })
      .each("end", repeat);
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JR6K9/)

Comment: In version 4 this was changed to .on instead of .each

Comment: exchanging `.each` with `.on` doesnt work in v4 or v5

Comment: For d3v4, much changed. `.each` became `.on` (for transition events, at least), `.ease("linear")` became `.ease(d3.easeLinear)`, and `.attr({})` got removed, in favor of multiple `.attr`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208860/6184972 for more information.