# Looping transition in D3 version 4 and 5

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js, transition

The example answer which was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232929/looping-transition-in-d3) works fine with D3 version 3, but in version 4/5 `.each` was changed to `.on` and the example doesn't work anymore, even if changing `.each` to `.on`. Is there anything else which have to be considered? Here is the fiddle and the code with D3 version 4: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/upwbmdzg/)

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);

// code, code, code, irrelevant code...

function timeForTimeline(){ // har
    var timeline = svg.append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue");
    repeat();

    function repeat() {
    timeline.attr({
        'x1': 0,
        'y1': 130,
        'x2': 168,
        'y2': 130
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr({
        'x1': 0,
        'y1': 430,
        'x2': 168,
        'y2': 430   
    })
    .each("end", repeat);
};
};



timeForTimeline();
```

Comment: This code is D3 v3. Please update your question and the fiddle with a v4/5 code, so we can check what's happening.

Comment: On the other hand, if your actual question is how to change it for v4/v5: 1. don't put objects in `attr`, and 2. change the `ease` value (besides the `each`, of course). After doing that, you'll see that this code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3v4 moved away from using object literals (i.e. `{}`) to set attributes (and classes and styles). You can add support back for setting attributes and styles by including d3-selection-multi (https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js), and calling `.attrs` instead of `.attr`. Alternatively you can just use multiple `.attr`.

Also, `.ease()` now takes an easing function instead of a string. For convenience, d3v4 includes a slew of easing functions (viewable at https://github.com/d3/d3-ease). You'd invoke it via something like *selection*.**ease**(`d3.easeLinear`).

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wqptuews/